# Why did Oyster card charge me £43 but only gave me a credit for £5?

Tags: price, england, tfl, oyster-card

This is my first time travelling to London and I'm very confused by the travel infrastructure here. When I landed at Heathrow, I bought a 7 day Oyster card for Zone 1-2 and I was charged £43 for it. After I took my journey to Central London and I saw the balance, it said that it had deduced £1.5 and my remaining balance was just £3.5.

Where did the rest of my £38 go?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The terminology does get confusing. Basically, you have an Oyster card with:

- A ***"7-day Zone 1 & 2 Travelcard"*** on it. This gives you free travel *within* Zones 1 & 2 for 7 days. [It is worth **£33** and it will...](https://visitorshop.tfl.gov.uk/tfl/london-travelcard/)

  > ...let you travel as often as you like on bus, Tube, tram, DLR, London Overground and National Rail services within the London travel zones [in this case, zones 1 and 2].
- **£5 credit** which is used when you travel outside of zones 1 and 2, or if you're still using it after the 7 days are up.
- **£5 deposit** paid, which you [can claim back if you return the card when you leave](https://tfl.gov.uk/fares-and-payments/replacements-and-refunds/oyster-refunds-and-replacements#on-this-page-2).

So, when you travelled from Heathrow (which is in Zone 6), you paid from the card's credit for the stretch of the journey to Zone 2. Now you're in central London, you get free tube and bus travel within Zone 1 & 2.

Comment: Ah ok. So just to clarify, for the next 7 days, I do not need to pay anything extra if I am travelling in zone 1 and 2?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It's called a "travelcard" and lets you "travel as often as you like on bus, Tube, tram, DLR, London Overground and National Rail services" within those zones and timeframe. For more info see https://visitorshop.tfl.gov.uk/tfl/london-travelcard/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Accepted the answer. They really need to do a better job of explaining this on their website.

Comment: Just to add to user568458's comment, bus travel is not zone restricted so you can use any London bus anywhere for free during the validity of the travelcard.

Comment: Note that since this answer was written new cards no longer have a "deposit", they have a "card fee". The card fee is refunded after a year but it can't be refunded in the short term.